# PyAudio recording/capturing and stop/terminate in Python on Raspi

Tags: raspbian, python, audio

I am not an expert of Python, trying to capture/record the Audio by USB audio device.
It is working fine on command terminal.
But I want to make a program which just recording audio and stop when I want.

I heard ab8 Pyaudio library which has certain API to perform this job(like pyaudio.PyAudio(), pyaudio.Pyaudio.open(), pyaudio.stream, pyaudio.stream.close, pyaudio.PyAudio.terminate().....

Can somebody help to make a simple program for audio recording in Python?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just add relevant comments in front of commands, let me know If you want to clear more ab8 it

```
import pyaudio, wave, sys

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 10


WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'Audio_.wav'
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
               channels = CHANNELS,
               rate = RATE,
               input = True,
               input_device_index = 0,
               frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()    # "Stop Audio Recording
stream.close()          # "Close Audio Recording
p.terminate()           # "Audio System Close

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```